# List of all profiles for a given permission on a given object

Tags: apex, profile

Is there any way (Apex or SOQL) to get list of all the profiles with "Modify All" access for a given object ?.

For example I am interested in all the profiles in my org which has the "Modify All" access on Account object.

Currently I need to go through each and every profile and check whether this permission is set or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to target the `PermisionSet` and `ObjectPermissions` objects to find profile permissions in relation to objects. The example below should give you what you were looking for in regards to profiles with Modify All on Accounts.

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Profile.Name
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId
             FROM ObjectPermissions
             WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' 
             AND PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true)
```