# How to determine if a given User can view a given FeedItem

Tags: permissions, profile, user, permission-sets, feeditem

I'm using the query API to retrieve `User` and `FeedItem` objects.

I want to be able to determine which users can read/view which feed items.

`FeedItem` has `Visibility` property, but it doesn't help much. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm):

> Specifies whether this feed item is available to all users or internal
> users only. This field is available in API version 26.0 and later, if
> digital experiences is enabled for your org. Visibility can have the
> following values:
>
> AllUsers — The feed item is available to all users who
> have permission to see the feed item.
>
> InternalUsers — The feed item is
> available to internal users only.

Best I could find was determining if a user has access to an `Account`, which seems too high level: [List of all profiles for a given permission on a given object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97284/list-of-all-profiles-for-a-given-permission-on-a-given-object)